# React: props.filter not working even though data is accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is props.tasks.filter in the TaskList component not working and causing an error?

I'm a able to access the props - I've JSON.stringified the props in the return and it displays the data properly.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddTask from '../src/components/AddTask';
import TaskList from '../src/components/TaskList';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(
    {
      name: 'Example 1',
      id: 1,
      important: true,
      targetDate: '2021-07-16',
      active: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Example 2',
      id: 2,
      important: false,
      targetDate: '2021-06-03',
      active: false,
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddTask />
      <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
      <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

TaskList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task';

const TaskList = (props) => {
  const active = props.tasks.filter((task) => task.active);
  const done = props.tasks.filter((task) => !task.active);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>{JSON.stringify(props.tasks)}</ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default TaskList;
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
TypeError: props.tasks.filter is not a function
  2 | import Task from './Task';
  3 | 
  4 | const TaskList = (props) => {
> 5 |   const active = props.tasks.filter((task) => task.active);
  6 |   const done = props.tasks.filter((task) => !task.active);
  7 | 
  8 |   return (
```

Comment: `causing an error` What's the error?

Comment: Sorry, updated it

Comment: You're missing the array brackets when you call useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `tasks` in your `useState` as array like this:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
{
  name: 'Example 1',
  id: 1,
  important: true,
  targetDate: '2021-07-16',
  active: true,
},
{
  name: 'Example 2',
  id: 2,
  important: false,
  targetDate: '2021-06-03',
  active: false,
}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked wonders! Still learning the hooks.. :)

Comment: You are welcome :), can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind object in react. But you have to map through them.

```
props.tasks.map(task=> <li className={task.active ? 'active' : 'done'}>{task}</li>)
```

Also, the state should be in array. Fix that typo.